# How does LINQ work when it should affect the previous calls in the chain? (e.g. mongo/Linq2Sql)

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

a thing baffled me with LINQ when i used MongoDB...
(for matter of fact, it is happening in Linq2Sql too)

1. `myCollection.Find(obj=>true)` will run query to return all documents of myCollection.
2. `myCollection.Find(obj=>true, new FindOptions(){Limit=1})` will obviously run query to return only one document from myCollection.
3. `myCollection.Find(obj=>true).First()` will also run query to return only one document from myCollection.

My question regarding #3: *What query is made to the server?*
*A.* `.First()` causes the `.Find()` method to perform an implicit `Limit=1` query to the server,
return only one document? (if so, how is that implemented?)

*B.* `.Find()` query all documents and `.First()` just take the first one and throw the rest? Seem wasteful.

thanks

Comment: Its implemented by (and dependent on) the *database provider* to potentially run on the database (in its native language)

Comment: Can't say for sure (have to look at the source) but the provider is supposed to translate that to the most efficient query for the database. In this case it SHOULD perform an implicit `Limit=1`

Comment: With entity framework, the query is only issued to the server when you try to enumerate the collection.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman is it the same "Enumerable" object that is passed through the entire chain? One that override "most" LINQ calls?
 my question regarding how does the prior call know what calls come later... if it is the same Object, I guess it is reasonable.

Comment: The linq functions on `IQueryable`, return another `IQueryable`. Collecting all of the `LambdaExpression`s that describe what you intend. It's getting the `IEnumerator` that causes the backend to generate the sequence of values, based on the entire `IQueryable` expression.

Answer (score 1):

`First` provided by MongoDB driver is a shortcut to `.Limit(1)`, and reads data from server as an object:

```
collection.Find(o => true).First();
// is equivalent to
collection.Find(o => true).Limit(1);
```

The query gets sent to the server should be:

```
db.collection.find().limit(1)
```

If it is not sending that or similar query, it will be a bug in MongoDB driver and you could contact them and file a bug.